# How do I get PointToScreen in UWP

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

In WPF something like this would tell me where the border top left corner:

```
        var point = myBorder.PointToScreen(new Point());
```

How do I get the same in UWP? I can't find any way to get it.

Thank you :)

Comment: I can't seem to find the question I saw this on recently to mark dupe but it was [UIElement.TransformToVisual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transformtovisual) I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TransformToVisual` method. Use the following code

```
var transformToVisual = myBorder.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
var borderCoordinats = transformToVisual .TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get the screen coordinates of UIElement in following steps:

1. Get the coordinates of UIElement relative to current application window by following codes:

   ```
   GeneralTransform transform = myBorder.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
   Point coordinatePointToWindow = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
   ```
2. Get the `Rect` information of current application window:

   ```
   Rect rect = Window.Current.CoreWindow.Bounds;
   ```
3. Calculate the coordinates of your UIElement:

   ```
   var left = coordinatePointToWindow.X + rect.Left;
   var top = coordinatePointToWindow.Y + rect.Top;
   ```

Comment: I accepted the other answer as it was first, but your gives me more info. Thank you :)